# SUDS does not parse response as array (only the first entry thereof is returned)

Tags: python, python-2.7, soap, soap-client, suds

A request using [the SUDS library](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/) to a SOAP web service should return an **array of** `EnvelopeType` instances (don't ask me for the type naming) but instead **only the first entry** of the array is parsed and returned. The `wsdl:type` of the response is defined as:

```
<wsdl:types>
  <xs:element name="ShipmentsSearchDFURes">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>Comment describing your root element</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="ZEnvelope" type="dfu:EnvelopeType"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</wsdl:types>
```

and a sample raw XML response (as obtained with `client.last_received()`) yields:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope>
   <soap:Body>
      <ns11:ShipmentsSearchDFURes>
         <Envelope Version="2.2">
            <FileInfos FileID="1" FileTime="16:10:13.110+02:00" FileDate="2014-06-18+02:00" />
            <Data>
              <!-- ... Omitted for brevity ... -->
            </Data>
         </Envelope>
         <Envelope Version="2.2">
            <FileInfos FileID="2" FileTime="16:12:13.117+02:00" FileDate="2014-06-18+02:00"/>
            <Data>
              <!--  ... -->
            </Data>
         </Envelope>
      </ns11:ShipmentsSearchDFURes>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I'm by no means a SOAP expert but I'd expect that calling

```
client.service.ShipmentsSearch(...)
```

would return an **array of** `EnvelopeType` instances but here **only the first entry**, i.e. with `FileID="1"`, is returned. That is, instead of returning:

```
[envelope_1, envelope_2]
```

I just get `envelope_1`. Thanks a million for any help.

Note #1: I am a mere consumer of the WebService.

Note #2: The PHP SOAP client does return an array of both the `EnvelopeType` instances. Could anything be wrong with SUDS? or with the WSDL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The partial parsing can partly be blamed on the erroneous type definition as

```
  <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:element name="ZEnvelope" type="dfu:EnvelopeType"/>
  </xs:sequence>
```

should read:

```
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="ZEnvelope" type="dfu:EnvelopeType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xs:sequence>
```

according to [XML Schema at W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#DefnDeclars). Using a local copy of the WSDL and the referenced files therein with the above changes solves the problem.

---

If you must know, when parsing the raw XML response SUDS will use the XSD schema and the ultimate reason for the bad parsing is due to a somewhat surprisingly stiff handling of the root nodes on lines 158–161 of the `Binding.get_reply()` method (in `bindings/binding.py`):

```
130     def get_reply(self, method, reply):
131         """
132         Process the I{reply} for the specified I{method} by sax parsing the I{reply}
133         and then unmarshalling into python object(s).
134         @param method: The name of the invoked method.
135         @type method: str
136         @param reply: The reply XML received after invoking the specified method.
137         @type reply: str
138         @return: The unmarshalled reply.  The returned value is an L{Object} for a
139             I{list} depending on whether the service returns a single object or a
140             collection.
141         @rtype: tuple ( L{Element}, L{Object} )
142         """
143         reply = self.replyfilter(reply)
144         sax = Parser()
145         replyroot = sax.parse(string=reply)
146         plugins = PluginContainer(self.options().plugins)
147         plugins.message.parsed(reply=replyroot)
148         soapenv = replyroot.getChild('Envelope')
149         soapenv.promotePrefixes()
150         soapbody = soapenv.getChild('Body')
151         self.detect_fault(soapbody)
152         soapbody = self.multiref.process(soapbody)
153         nodes = self.replycontent(method, soapbody)
154         rtypes = self.returned_types(method)
155         if len(rtypes) > 1:
156             result = self.replycomposite(rtypes, nodes)
157             return (replyroot, result)
158         if len(rtypes) == 1:
159             if rtypes[0].unbounded():
160                 result = self.replylist(rtypes[0], nodes)
161                 return (replyroot, result)
162             if len(nodes):
163                 unmarshaller = self.unmarshaller()
164                 resolved = rtypes[0].resolve(nobuiltin=True)
165                 result = unmarshaller.process(nodes[0], resolved)
166                 return (replyroot, result)
167         return (replyroot, None)
```

where the author solely relies on the type definition regardless of the size of the `nodes` list. Specifically, I think that the test on line 159 should rather read:

```
158         if len(rtypes) == 1:
159             if rtypes[0].unbounded() or len(nodes)>1:
160                 result = self.replylist(rtypes[0], nodes)
161                 return (replyroot, result)
```

perhaps with a warning of the mismatch between the XSD and the actual response. HTH.